# Use bazel to build the project If multiple modules have dependencies on each other, is there a way to compile them separatel?

Tags: c, bazel

This project was previously built using CMake.
Currently, I am rebuilding the project through bazel. There are multiple modules that have dependencies on each other.

Is there a way to compile it into a library file separately, or can it only be compiled into one large library file?

For example, The header file used by the current module is in other directories (not in subdirectories). I can't find this header file using includes or copts, and I can't put it into srcs! ! !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.